# Generating flow map with varying width and alpha level which accumulates using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, network, flow-map

I'm using ArcMap.

I have a very large line shapefile with ~300'000 links which all have the attribute `flow` (a numeric variable from 0-200).

My goal is to display a map like in this example (produced in QGIS):

[image: flow map]

This map is from the following [this](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/flows/) link. There are more

Basically I want to have a varying (and adjustable) width of the links, according to the value of `flow`. Ideally, the color of the links should contain an alpha value, to see overlapping links accumulate.

I have not been able to find anything on codeshare that could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not constrained to using ArcMap, take a look at [Flowmap.blue](https://flowmap.blue/). It can handle 300K flows.

[image: Flowmap.blue screenshot]